AWS Bedrock and AWS Knowledgebase,
Does anyone have an idea on how to integrate AWS Bedrock and AWS Knowledgebase on code. I have already synced my Bedrock and AWS Knowledgebase.
i am trying to make sure that the code works. and it would help alot thanks.

You will need to create an Agent within AWS Bedrock.
You can then associate the knowledge base with the Agent so that this source of information can be used to answer questions.
Programatically, you will need to call the AWS Bedrock API, specifically the invoke_agent method.
Read all about it here.
